# I have to run a command in shell script and that command is asking for username and password and I want to hardcode it in script

Tags: shell

[image]

Here I am running a script which contains a command.
It is asking to enter user name and password.
But i want to hard-code it.

Comment: We can't see the script you're running, because you didn't include that source code. How do you expect anyone to tell you how to change it when we can't see what it is doing now? Your image is useless for anything except a waste of data for those reading this site on a mobile device. Strange how you included the notice from Oracle about needing written permission to use it, though... Do you have that permission to automate use of this utility?

Comment: Sorry..I just want to run the command adcgnjar.Which will asks for username and password.I just want to hard-code the username and password in the script.